# A way to check if the temporary table exists or not

Tags: sybase, sap-ase

I have this following query :

```sql
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM   sysobjects
               WHERE  id = Object_id('tempdb..TEMP_THETH_DETAILS'))
  EXECUTE (
'CREATE TABLE tempdb..TEMP_THETH_DETAILS( THETH_ID NUMERIC(5) NOT NULL, LANGUAGE VARCHAR(3) DEFAULT ''EN'' NOT NULL)'
)

GO
```

The problem is the checking, it seems tempdb doesnt take on consideration if not exist, maybe because the table was create in the tempdb.
 So my question is there a way I can check if the temporary table exists or not ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```sql
IF object_id('tempdb..TEMP_THETH_DETAILS') is null
begin
   EXECUTE 
   (
       'CREATE TABLE tempdb..TEMP_THETH_DETAILS
        ( THETH_ID NUMERIC(5) NOT NULL, 
          LANGUAGE VARCHAR(3) DEFAULT ''EN'' NOT NULL
        )'
    )
end
go
```

Comment: parado I dont want to create it as #temp_ .. because i want  the table to be insrted in the MDB sybase database , creating as #tem will be deleted when the sesions ends which I dont want that. its like similar in oracle global temporary table

Comment: I'm glad I cloud help you!

Answer (score 0):

You can catch exception when checking for table existence and execute code if an exception was intercepted.

In Sybase:

```
begin

  declare SQLE_TABLE_NOT_FOUND EXCEPTION FOR SQLSTATE '42W33';

  ...

  if exists(select 'x
              from #tmpTable) then

    -- TODO

  endif;

  -- at the end of the function if table not exists,

  -- thrown exception is catched here

  exception when SQLE_TABLE_NOT_FOUND then

    -- TODO

end;
```

Comment: uhmm its an old question, however i will check you answer maybe something new for me

Answer (score -2):

use tempdb

```
GO

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
           FROM   sysobjects
           WHERE  id = Object_id('tempdb..TEMP_THETH_DETAILS'))
EXECUTE (
    'CREATE TABLE tempdb..TEMP_THETH_DETAILS( THETH_ID NUMERIC(5) NOT NULL,
    LANGUAGE VARCHAR(3) DEFAULT ''EN'' NOT NULL)'
)

GO
```

Comment: sorry what is the difference ?